# SQL LIKE literally not showing any results (at all)

Tags: php, sql

I tried to make a search system which uses the LIKE operator to search results based on what the user typed. I'm using it with strings. The problem is that it doesn't show any result.

I hope this also helps people with the same confusion as me...

Code:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ' . $input . ';";
```

input is a PHP variable from what the user typed.

EDIT: Don't worry about SQL injection, it's all offline.

Comment: 1) Strings need to be quoted. Or use prepared statements/parameter binding. 2) `LIKE` without wildcard is going to be a case-insensitive exact search.

Comment: PHP variables begin with `$`. Show your actual PHP code. It would be best if you used prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @aynber I did include quotes on strings. I copied only the SQL part of the code.

Comment: @Barmar I copied the code manually from my text editor. I didn't CTRL-C-V it. I copied it manually because my text editor copies things in a strange and peculiar way and the text gets all confused and messy. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the proper use of like  you should  use  wildchar  eg :

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%')  ;
```

and you should not use  var inside SQL code  ..  you are at risk for sqlinjectiomn

for avoid this you should take a look at you db driver for prepared  statement and binding param

eg for PDO

```
$st  = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%')");
$st->bindParam(1, $input, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
$st->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$string = "input";
$sql = "select * from table where name like '%$string%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and store value what you want to search

```
$where = "AND name like '%$string%'";
```

and put it after table name

```
$sql = "select * from table_name $where";
```